# How to statistically compare the outcome of two classification algorithms?

Tags: statistics

I have two deep learning classifiers and I want to make a test statistic to compare their performance against each other. The two algorithms have been tested on the same 60 samples and have an accuracy of 78.6% and 91.8% respectively. How do I compare their performance? Would I use Students paired t-test in this scenario?

Comment: Not that it matters but you cannot get accuracy of 78.6% and 91.8% from a sample of 60

Comment: It's 61, I just rounded it off for whatever reason.

Comment: OK, so 48 and 56 correct predictions out of 61, i.e. 13 and 5 incorrect predictions.  One issue to note with a paired $t$-test is that you will need to know the overlap of correct/incorrect answers for the two algorithms to calculate the significance of the difference (if the 5 are a subset of the 13 then the significance will be higher than if all 18 are disjoint) and this effect and requirement may be desirable or not.

Comment: I see. I do have that information since I have the outcome of each sample. But what I'm gathering from your answer is that a paired t test would be valid in this case, which I wasn't sure of.